# Java Restore Key Binding to Default

Tags: java, swing, binding, key

I asked this question a little earlier, but maybe some of you were asleep, as where I live at the time it was probably very early in silicon valley.
My program has assigned new functions to the arrow keys, but for the very last part of the Swing display's presentation I need them to function normally within a TextArea, moing the cursor and such.

Is there a way to restore to defaults, or through an AbstractAction assign simple movement of the cursor once again?

Comment: loved the starting :D :'D

Answer (score 1):

The original answer I gave you showed how to replace the Action. If you need to restore the default Action then it is probably easier to create a new InputMap and ActionMap entry for the Action. The [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) link I gave you shows how to do this.

Then when you need to restore the default Action you can use:

```
textField.getInputMap().put(keystroke, "none");
```

This will cause the original InputMap to be search again.

Another approach it to save the Action before you update the ActionMap with the custom Action. Something like:

```
Action original = textField.getActionMap().get(...);
```

Reread the [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) link to better understand the usage of the InputMap and ActionMap.